# Adjust SVG background width and height

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to achieve this:
[image]

But I was not able to change the rect's width/height. Is there a way to change the svg's background width and height only (without affecting the the logo)?

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#4267b2" />
<path d="M11.9756 0.0498047C5.36171 0.0498047 0 5.41152 0 12.0254C0 17.9572 4.31743 22.8698 9.97829 23.8211V14.5238H7.08943V11.1781H9.97829V8.71109C9.97829 5.84866 11.7266 4.28881 14.2804 4.28881C15.5036 4.28881 16.5547 4.37995 16.8599 4.42009V7.41209L15.0886 7.41295C13.7 7.41295 13.4323 8.07266 13.4323 9.04109V11.1764H16.7456L16.3134 14.5221H13.4323V23.9011C19.3574 23.1799 23.951 18.1422 23.951 12.0219C23.951 5.41152 18.5893 0.0498047 11.9756 0.0498047Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer suggest the use of transform="scale() translate()" but there are better and more optimal options. The main problem with your rect is that you omitted the x and y values.

Try one of the following:

1- Open the svg on Inkscape, Illustrator or CorelDraw and change the size of the background rect.

2- Do the same as in 1 but additionally select both, rect and icon and combine them in a single path.

3- Open the svg file in a text editor and change the viewBox, then change the width, height and x y values of the rect. Just like this:

Answer (score 2):

```html
<svg width="126" height="88" viewBox="0 0 63 44" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#4267b2" rx="6"/>
<path d="M11.9756 0.0498047C5.36171 0.0498047 0 5.41152 0 12.0254C0 17.9572 4.31743 22.8698 9.97829 23.8211V14.5238H7.08943V11.1781H9.97829V8.71109C9.97829 5.84866 11.7266 4.28881 14.2804 4.28881C15.5036 4.28881 16.5547 4.37995 16.8599 4.42009V7.41209L15.0886 7.41295C13.7 7.41295 13.4323 8.07266 13.4323 9.04109V11.1764H16.7456L16.3134 14.5221H13.4323V23.9011C19.3574 23.1799 23.951 18.1422 23.951 12.0219C23.951 5.41152 18.5893 0.0498047 11.9756 0.0498047Z" fill="white"
 transform="translate(19.5,10)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform="scale() translate()"` on path

```css
svg {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="140px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 14 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="140px" height="70px" fill="#4267b2" />
<path d="M11.9756 0.0498047C5.36171 0.0498047 0 5.41152 0 12.0254C0 17.9572 4.31743 22.8698 9.97829 23.8211V14.5238H7.08943V11.1781H9.97829V8.71109C9.97829 5.84866 11.7266 4.28881 14.2804 4.28881C15.5036 4.28881 16.5547 4.37995 16.8599 4.42009V7.41209L15.0886 7.41295C13.7 7.41295 13.4323 8.07266 13.4323 9.04109V11.1764H16.7456L16.3134 14.5221H13.4323V23.9011C19.3574 23.1799 23.951 18.1422 23.951 12.0219C23.951 5.41152 18.5893 0.0498047 11.9756 0.0498047Z" fill="white" transform="scale(0.2) translate(23,13)"  />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the id to the svg and add styles for this id.

**HTML**:

```
<svg id="test" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#4267b2" />
<path d="M11.9756 0.0498047C5.36171 0.0498047 0 5.41152 0 12.0254C0 17.9572 4.31743 22.8698 9.97829 23.8211V14.5238H7.08943V11.1781H9.97829V8.71109C9.97829 5.84866 11.7266 4.28881 14.2804 4.28881C15.5036 4.28881 16.5547 4.37995 16.8599 4.42009V7.41209L15.0886 7.41295C13.7 7.41295 13.4323 8.07266 13.4323 9.04109V11.1764H16.7456L16.3134 14.5221H13.4323V23.9011C19.3574 23.1799 23.951 18.1422 23.951 12.0219C23.951 5.41152 18.5893 0.0498047 11.9756 0.0498047Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

**CSS**:

```
  #test {
      width:25px;
      height:25px;
    }
```